# Installing and updating SUDO on Centos 7 has caused all websites connection error

Tags: ssh, connection, centos7, sudo

I have executed the following on SSH on my Centos 7 VPS following a tutorial

```
sudo yum install epel-release -y
sudo yum update -y
sudo shutdown -r now
```

After which all my websites hosted on the same VPS went down and are giving connection error. 
I am still able to connect to SSH and Plesk however. I am unable to get help from my hosting company as they said it is my sole responsibility.

How can I approach to solve this issue? (Note: I am beginner to SSH.)

Comment: Create a backup of your system. Now.

Comment: Delete your question here and ask at [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the servers:

```
sudo service httpd restart
sudo service mysqld restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by restarting NGINX and APACHE, apparently it was a conflict between the 2 after restart and has nothing to do with sudo installation.
For Centos 7

```
systemctl stop nginx.service
systemctl restart httpd.service
apachectl graceful
systemctl restart nginx.service
```

I followed the guide from this page https://wpguru.co.uk/2015/04/how-to-fix-apachenginx-trouble-after-restarting-your-plesk-server/ in case anyone needed it.